# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not Found While sending email from Nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nodemailer

I am trying to develop a mail sending module in my NestJs project. when I send the mail through my local machine it works fine. But when it goes to the server (digital-ocean droplet) it throws the following error and it does not send any email further. what is going on and fix this?

[image: Error on server]

My code segment is below:

1. Auth controller

   ```
    @Post('register')
     async register(@Body() register: RegisterRequest) {
       const res = await this.authService.register(register);
       if (res instanceof Error) {
         throw res;
       }
       return {
         statusCode: 200,
         message:
           'Your account is registered successfully. Please check your email to verify your account',
       };
     }
   ```
2. Auth Service

   ```
   async register(register: RegisterRequest): Promise<any> {
     register.isRegister = true;
     register.status = 0;
     register.roleId = 5;
     const user = await this.userService.save(register);
     console.log('User Saved');
     if (user instanceof User) {
       if (register.isRegister) {
         console.log('IS REGISTER');
         // Generate Token
         const resultsToken = await this.userTokenService.save(user.id, 1);
         console.log('USER TOKEN SAVED');
         if (resultsToken) {
           this.mailService.sendUserConfirmation(user, resultsToken.token);
         }
     }
   }
   return user;
   }
   ```
3. User Service

   ```
   async save(register: RegisterRequest): Promise<User> {
   try {
     const token = generateToken(8);
     const user = new User();
     user.email = register.email;
     user.firstName = register.firstName;
     user.lastName = register.lastName;
     user.password = hashPassword(register.password || token);
     user.role = register.roleId;
     user.phoneNumber = register.phoneNumber;
     user.isActive = register.status;
     const errors = await validate(user);
     if (errors.length > 0) {
       throw new ParameterMissingException(
         errors[0].constraints[Object.keys(errors[0].constraints)[0]],
       );
     }
     const existing = await this.findOneByEmail(register.email);
     if (existing) {
       throw new EntityFoundException('Email');
     }
     const registered = await this.userRepository.save(user);
     return registered;
   } catch (error) {
     return error;
   }
   }
   ```
4. User Token service

   ```
   async save(userId: number, type: number): Promise<UserToken> {
   try {
     const userToken = new UserToken();
     userToken.user = userId;
     userToken.type = type;
     userToken.token = generateToken();
     if (type === 2) {
       userToken.expireIn = 15;
     }
     console.log('USER TOKEN SAVE');
     return await this.userTokenRepository.save(userToken);
   } catch (error) {
     console.log('USER TOKEN ERROR');
     return error;
   }
   }
   ```
5. Mail Service

   ```
   sendUserConfirmation(user: any, token: string) {
   const url = `${
     this.configService.get<string>('REGISTER_CONFIRM_URL') + token
   }`;
   console.log('MAIL SERVICE ' + url);
   this.mailerService
     .sendMail({
       to: user.email,
       // from: '"Support Team" <support@example.com>', // override default from
       subject: 'Greetings from CEWAS!',
       template: join(__dirname, 'templates') + './register-confirmation',
       context: {
         url,
       },
     })
     .then((r) => console.log(r))
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log('MAIL SERVICE ERROR');
       console.log(err);
     });
   }
   ```
6. Mail Module and Config

   ```
   import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
   import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs- 
   modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
   import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
   import { MailService } from './mail.service';
   import { join } from 'path';

   @Module({
    imports: [
     MailerModule.forRoot({
     transport: {
       service: 'gmail',
       secure: true,
       auth: {
         user: '********@gmail.com',
         pass: '********',
       },
     },
     defaults: {
       from: '"<No Reply>" <*******@gmail.com>',
     },
     template: {
       dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
       adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
       options: {
         strict: true,
         },
        },
      }),
    ],
    providers: [MailService],
    exports: [MailService],
   })
    export class MailModule {}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try whit this configuration in your transport:

```
transport: {
     host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
     port: 465,
     ignoreTLS: true,
     secure: true,
     auth: {
       user: '********@gmail.com', //use the .env variable here for security
       pass: '********'
     },
}
```

and make sure you turned on access for less secure app

here the link: [less secure app](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4PiPGuFZqs2GcubkBSdCIm_DVpUKFgOq0Q39v-kW70dlFV8a2mxDxDN-BENjtfAIkI8ze5DgkWiBSlQWY4XFBZcpwYA6g)